# Unwanted scroll on click on last item in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, scrollviewer

Case: ItemsControl with Virtualizing enabled (performance). Contains checkboxes/textboxes/etc.  However, clicking on checkbox/textbox on last visible item causes itemscontrol to scroll down instead of selecting the checkbox/textbox.
With virtualizing disabled, everything works fine...
I have tried a lot of things (using ListView, wrapping it in larger panel, etc.). No luck.

ItemsSource is set in code behind to a large dataset of testitems with properties Name and ID.

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewTestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="525" Background="AliceBlue">

<ItemsControl x:Name="MainListView" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding}" Width="525">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Height="50" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <CheckBox Height="50" Content="Checkbox" Grid.Row="1" />
                <TextBox Height="50" Grid.Row="2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Focusable="False">
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by using this solution:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/16/implementing-a-virtualizingpanel-part-4-the-goods.aspx

thus, by implementing iscrollinfo and implementing the virtualization manually.

Comment: Is the only way to solve this by turning off virtualization or implementing it manually?